# I have PCs A and B with Windows 10 in a LAN to share files. PC B sees A, but A does not see B. How can I resolve this?

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, network-shares, file-sharing

I want to share files in both directions between two computers in a wired LAN. Both use the same account credentials (an MS @live.com account). Both are Windows 10, both are in the same subnet (192.168.0.xxx) plugged into the same router/switch. As far as I can see I have used the same settings for file sharing in both, but both show only pc "A" under "Network" with the Windows Explorer. I.e., pc "A" shows only its own shared files and folders and "B" also shows only the shared folders of "A" but not its own.
Normally, each pc would show the shared folders of both computers.
This, to my understanding, means that there is a working connection, but there is a file-sharing or networking problem with pc "B" only.
The problem is, as far as I know I have done all the directly available settings in "advanced settings for file sharing" in "B" exactly the same as in "A".
What else should I check?
(BTW my Windows is in Spanish, so if someone can advise with Spanish names for the settings and especially the services to check, it would help a lot, but if not possible, English will do.)

Comment: On both computers: 
1. Ensure Network Discovery, File / Print Sharing, and passwords are enabled.
2. Ensure the same WORKGROUP.
3. Make sure Wireless connections are Private.
4. If you share by computer name (not IP address), you need a HOSTS file entry.
5. If both computers use the same username and password, restart and test.
If the user names are different, put a name/password on the Main (Sharing) Computer that is the same as the other computer.

Comment: Workgroup remains in Windows 10 (Start, Settings, Advanced Settings and workgroup is in the traditional spot). HOST file entry should look like 192.168.1.x Name # Description.  Subnet should be the same for both machines. Microsoft Account works best if same for both machines.  I do not have to adjust any services (and do not) to share folders.

Comment: John, thanks again. I had not noticed that the host file that I had found was in an old backup. So there does not seem to exist an actual host file. In which folder should I create it and does it have an extension like .txt? Will it be populated automatically by the DHCP server or do I need to give fixed addresses to all PCs and enter them manually in the HOST file?

Comment: You need the HOST file to relate Name to IP address so it is best to use fixed IP address for that machine. Fixed IP is good also for sharing with IP address.

Comment: You need to put the entries in the HOST file yourself as it is not automatic.

Comment: Thanks again. I have now done everything as you advised.
1) Network discovery etc all set the same way in both. I deactivated the requirement for a password in both to avoid the nuisance to need the credentials every time. 
2) Both have WORKGROUP, checked with >net config workstation
3) Connections are private, via LAN cable.
4) I edited the hosts files in both to contain the same names and IP#, then rebooted
5) Both use same MS account (always have)
Now PC B can access PC A, but PC A does not see nor access PC B.

Comment: I will do some thinking. I am not sure why A cannot see  B.  I have three machines here and they all see each other, so I am not sure why in your case.

Comment: This is really strange.
I have now added a 3rd PC ("C") via WiFi with the same settings and it is seen and accessible by both A & B, but cannot access either. It sees A but cannot access it and it does not even see B.
Thank you for your patience.